# How do we tell metaphor vs literal writings in the OT?

Tags: genesis, scriptures

For example, many Christians today believe in directed evolution - which seems to be in direct opposition to Genesis. If Genesis can be interpreted as metaphor, how can original sin and the rest of the Bible be understood?

Comment: This question is answered within the archives of the site. It is a very broad question (and for that reason it may be voted for closure) and covers a wide variety of more precise questions which have already been dealt with in detail. But I agree with your thesis that viewing scripture (broadly) as 'metaphor' (whenever one feels inclined to do so) simply dismisses the truth that scripture conveys. (A link to the meaning of 'directed evolution' would possibly be of assistance to your readership.)

Comment: You might consider that metaphors are used to simplify ideas to make them easier to understand. The seven days of creation is hardly simpler or easier to understand than saying "In the beginning, God created everything.", so my first thought would be that it *isn't* intended as metaphor.